# How can I save/restore window positions when I undock/dock my laptop?

Tags: x11, gnome3, laptop, window-management

I have a laptop with a docking station that has a large monitor connected to it.  When the laptop is docked, I use the monitor as my primary display, and the laptop screen as a secondary display.

When I undock, the laptop screen becomes my primary display, and all the windows move over to it.  When I dock the laptop, the monitor automatically becomes the primary display again, but the windows all stay on the laptop screen.  I have to drag each one over to the monitor and resize it.

**How can I get my windows to automatically resume the positions and sizes they had just before I undocked (assuming they're still open)?**  All I've been able to find are answers talking about restoring programs when you log in.  That's not what I'm looking for.

I'm using Gnome 3 on Arch Linux.

Comment: I have a similar problem: When I run a game that demands full screen mode but doesn't support my native resolution, all windows move around and get resized. It would be great to have a way to save / restore them.

Answer (score 2):

I have asked [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411503/is-there-a-dynamic-multiple-monitor-friendly-desktop-environment-available-for-u) on ask ubuntu and the accepted answer contains (not-ubuntu specific) shell scripts to save / restore window positions.

The key point is to use **[wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/)** to list active windows and **[xwininfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xwininfo)** to query their geometry and later **wmctrl** again to restore each window's geometry back.

**wmctrl** has to be installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come up with a script but ran out of time. You can find the related discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/xdotool-users/ns-pHfwQErc/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old forum, but I came across this while looking for a solution myself... I ended up spending 3 whole work days learning how to script in the Auto HotKey language and I created a nice script that stores window sizes and positions and then restores them after you re-dock your PC! Have a look and feel free to download or fork it from GitHub if you like it: https://github.com/jkos95/Undocking-Script

Edit: This only works for Windows PCs that I am aware of!

Comment: Please take the quick [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how Q&A sites like SE differ from forums. Please also see advice on [how to write a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). IIt's a good idea to check the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) on every new community you join - the expectations differ depending on the focus of the site. This kind of answers often get flagged for quality and may get [deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)[From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/390668)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your statement _"This only works for Windows PCs"_ make your solution off-topic for this site, which is about Unix&Linux. You may want to take it over to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) if you find a similar question there.